# Iterating geojson object with javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am working on a geodjango project and need to iterate over the geojson response from the server with javascript so i can pass it onto google maps. I need only coordinates "25.92" and "-80,..." returned from json iteration. I have tried various scripts with no success hoping someone can give me a quick answer.

```
{ "crs" : null,
  "features" : [ { "geometry" : { "coordinates" : [ 25.924292000000001,
                -80.124313999999998
              ],
            "type" : "Point"
          },
        "id" : 1,
        "properties" : {  },
        "type" : "Feature"
      } ],
  "type" : "FeatureCollection"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where 'obj' is the variable representing this object:

Access like this

```
obj.features[0].geometry.coordinates;
```

Assign like this

```
var lat = obj.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0],
     lon = obj.features[0].geometry.coordinates[1];
```

Answer (score 4):

I would do something like this:

```
var latLons = obj.features.map(function (o) {
    return {lat: o.geometry.coordinates[0], lon: o.geometry.coordinates[1]};
});
```

This makes sense if you could have multiple latLongs. This will give an array of objects with lat and lon defined to what you expect. If you only care about the first, then do `latLons[0]`.